# Is Kafka 2.4 compatible with Spark 2.4?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

When Updating Kafka from 2.3 to 2.4, what(if any) considerations are required to be taken regarding Spark? Will it affect the existing Spark version?

Comment: You could install both locally and try it out. What specific issues are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Kafka Broker to consume some produced messages from Spark 2.1 using a Kafka 2.4 client
I think Kafka 2.4 would be supported with Spark 2.4 (you can install them both on local and try to produce/consume a helloWorld topic)

In case you are interested in sbt dependencies :

```
val sparkVersion21 = "2.1.0"

lazy val dependencies = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"    %% "spark-core"            % sparkVersion21,
  "org.apache.spark"    %% "spark-sql"             % sparkVersion21,
  "org.apache.spark"    %% "spark-hive"            % sparkVersion21,
  "org.apache.spark"    %% "spark-yarn"            % sparkVersion21,
  "org.apache.kafka"    %  "kafka-clients"         % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.kafka"    %% "kafka"                 % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.kafka"    %  "kafka-streams"         % "2.4.0")
```